# How to perform AND operation in Mongodb for a query on nested array of objects

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have the following records:

```
Record 1:  
{
    "status": "active",
    "users": [
        {
            "name": "foo",
            "status": "a"
        },
        {
            "name": "foo",
            "status": "b"
        }        
    ]
}

Record 2:  
{
    "status": "active",
    "users": [
        {
            "name": "bar",
            "status": "a"
        },
        {
            "name": "foo",
            "status": "b"
        }        
    ]
}
```

Now, I wish to return only those records in which the `user.name` is "foo" and the `user.status` is "a" - That is I need to get Record 1 back since it satisfies my requirements.

How do I do the AND operation on the array within the record to achieve this?
I tried the following query:

```
{
    "$and": [
        {
            "users.name": "foo"
        },
        {
            "users.status": "a"
        }
    ]
}
```

but I get both the records - I need only the first record (since in the users array, it has an entry where the name is "foo" AND the status is "a").

Any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer out [here](http://learnmongo.com/posts/reaching-inside-with-dot-notation-and-elemmatch/)

The solution would be to have a query as follows:

```
{
    "users": {
        "$elemMatch": {
            "name": "foo",
            "status": "a"
        }
    }
}
```

That did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of individual field values you can also use whole objects in find queries. Try:

```
db.collection.find( { 
    users: {
         "name":"foo",
         "status":"a"
    }
});
```

This should return all documents where the users array includes an object (or is an object) which looks as described. But note that this doesn't work when the object has additional fields.

Comment: So you mean to say that if `users` array contains objects and these objects contain fields other than `name` and `status`, then the above query will not work? In my scenario, yes - the object contains fields other than the two mentioned, but I do not wish to include them in the query - how do I go about it then?

Comment: @Philipp please note that your answer won't work correctly - it will only match the *exact* object {"name":"foo","status":"a"} - it won't even match users that has those two fields in the opposite order!